# Launching system and third party apps in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I have searched ALOT now, i cant find a solid way to run apps like calendar, camera, facebook, twitter, insatgram, and all kinds of apps in android. I know that i need to use intents, but HOW can i do it? I really need help! Please help me and thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to launch some other application from your android application then you should know the package name for that particular application For example for launching facebook use

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Otherwise this can also be used

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

If you want to launch the default android applications installed for some particular kind of operation then you can use [implicit intents](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) for that. For example to start a browser you can use

```
Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.android.com");
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
startActivity(intent);
```

You should take also take a look at [intents and intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and [how to allow other apps to open your application](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html).

Comment: I just wanna say that this question had only 2 answers, @CommonsWare and mine, and mine got chosen. Today is the greatest day of my life!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept in Android as "run apps". You start activities. Talented developers do not focus on specific apps (e.g., "facebook, twitter, insatgram"), because those apps may not exist on any given device. Instead, you focus on generic capabilities (e.g., use an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` with `startActivity()` to share something, create a launcher by using `PackageManager` to find those activities that support `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME`).